Undefined variable with @use Glenn Marks extension
Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks (not the old Ritwick Dey one) gives the following error substituting @import for @use:

"Error: Undefined variable."

I've placed my finished project onto Github if that's relevant

Hello, make sure to give enough information if you want people to help you. What variable is undefined, what's the line throwing the error, in which file, etc...

if you have @use 'variables';, variables need to be accessed as variables.$variable-name.
// _variables.scss
$primary-color: #3498db;



// main.scss
@use 'variables';

body {
  color: variables.$primary-color;
}


But they are added with @use 'varaibles' as *;  so with that I can just write as it
